# What's the difference between `all: unset` and `all: revert'

Tags: css

As per MDN:

> The revert keyword works exactly the same as unset in many cases. The
>   only difference is for properties that have values set by the browser
>   or by custom stylesheets created by users (set on the browser side).

I don't understand the browser and custom stylesheet. Both browser and custom stylesheet can be replaced by `all: unset` also, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the MDN:

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the `inherit` keyword in the first case, and like the `initial` keyword in the second case.

So `unset` is either `inherit` or `initial`

> The revert CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property from its current value to the value the property **would have had if no changes had been made by the current style origin** to the current element. Thus, it resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or to the default value established by the user agent's stylesheet (or by user styles, if any exist).

Suppose the browser apply a default style to your element. Using `revert`, you will put back those styles while `unset` will not.

Example:

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p style="margin:revert">
  some text here
</p>
<p style="margin:unset">
  some text here
</p>
```

In the above example, the revert will erase the `50px` margin and will put back the default margin applied by the browser. In the second case, unset will simply set the margin to `initial` (which is `0`).

<sup>The revert value is not supported in all the browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value</sup>

---

In case no default styles are applied, `revert` will behave the same as `unset`

> The revert keyword works exactly the same as unset in many cases. The only difference is for properties **that have values set by the browser or by custom stylesheets created by users** (set on the browser side).

---

`all` is a shorthand for all the properties so the same logic described above apply to each property.

---

More examples:

```css
p {
  margin: 50px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

.box {
  color: red;
  display:unset;
}

p {
  color:unset; /* I will be inherit so I will keep the red color*/
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p style="margin:revert;border:revert;display:revert;">
    some "block" text that should have no border and default browser margin
  </p>
  <p style="margin:unset;border:unset;display:unset;">
    some "inline" text that should have no border and no margin
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `unset` keyword will first try to fall back to inherited property values, while revert will directly fall back to browser/custom stylesheet. As per MDN:

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, and like the initial keyword in the second case.

[unset - CSS @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

Comment: "The unset keyword will first try to fall back to inherited property values" - so that `revert` - "resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent" - see top answer

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers above are thorough enough in explaining the subtleties in these special "reset" property values. Most developers get tripped up by **inheritable** vs **non-inheritable** properties when using them.

For starters, **all**, **revert**, and **unset** will never work for Internet Explorer. So they should always be combined with other solutions.

Lets start with **all:revert** first, as it defines **all:unset**, as well, except for one  main difference explained below. When you assign **all:revert** to an element(s), it does the following:

1. Any **inheriting** properties (usually text-based like font or color, etc) you assigned to your element via style sheets are now removed and assigned a value of "inherit" and `and styles from either the body element or the browser's UA default style sheet only` now pass down to it through normal inheritance. The ones you directly assigned or changed via custom styles are removed and replaced with these inherited values via the "inherit" value now assigned them.
2. Any **non-inheritable** property values (like display or border, etc.) you assigned to your element via style sheets are removed from the element `and styles from the browser's UA default style sheet only` are assigned to the element. This is usually the default style sheet the browser came with when you installed it.
3. The above rules assume you do not have more selective styles that cascade over "revert" for any property on the element you are reverting. "all:revert" is just like any other CSS property so anything that cascades over any property on that element would individually win over the list of properties "all:revert" resets on that element.

Example of how this works:

INHERITABLE PROPERTY
If you had assigned a special "font-family:sans-serif" property (inheritable) to a "div" but "all:revert" was now assigned to that div, "sans-serif" would be removed from "font" and and it would now inherit the font-family value in the cascade from the parent tree above your div. It could be several parents up or coming from the "body" element, for example.

NON-INHERITABLE PROPERTY
If you assigned a custom "border:2px solid blue;" value (non-inheritable) to that same "div" but "all:revert" was now assigned to that div, that border would be removed and the browser's default value for "border" on "div" (assigned in your browser's UA default style sheet) would be used. This is almost always "none" for "border on "div".

What **all:unset** does is the same, but falls back to "initial" for non-inheritable property values, which isn't the browsers UA style sheet default, or even the element's default value for that property, but the universal default value for the property itself regardless of the element using it. That is quite nasty and not what most people want. Example: on "div" setting "display:unset" would default to "display:inline", not "display:block" like you would expect.

Comment: Good answer. The div displayed inline when `all:unset` is applied, that explained to me the difference between _revert_ and _unset_.

Answer (score 2):

`revert` and `unset` are identical except when the default css value for a property is different than the value set by the browser - or by custom stylesheets created by the user.

For example the css default value for `display` is `inline` for all elements including divs, so if you set `display:unset`, it will act as if `display:initial` which is the same as `display:inline`, however we know that browsers set `display:block` for divs.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <p> This div use unset, now divs display will be inline</p>
  <div style="display:unset;"> text</div>
  <div style="display:unset;"> text</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <p> This div use revert, now divs display will be block (the browser value or the value created by the user)</p>
  <div style="display:revert;"> text</div>
  <div style="display:revert;"> text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few values that each property can take on. As pointed out in Stokely's answer, a distinction must be made between inherited and non-inherited properties.

**initial**
This value is used to give a property the initial value specified by the specification, such as `color: initial;`. Please note that the initial value is often not the user agent's default style sheet value set by the browser.

**inherit**
This value is used when a property should inherit the computed value of its parent, such as `*{box-sizing: inherit;}`.

**unset**
This keyword acts like the value `inherit` for an inherited property and like the value `initial` for non-inherited properties.

**revert**
The value results solely from the cascade of user and user agent, so competing rules of the author are ignored when setting the value. However, these rules remain valid according to their specificity.

**all**
The shorthand property all can take on any of the above global values. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all this value will then be used for all properties except `unicode-bidi` and `direction`.

The quote

> The revert CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property
> from its current value to the value the property would have had if no
> changes had been made by the current style origin to the current
> element. Thus, it resets the property to its inherited value if it
> inherits from its parent or to the default value established by the
> user agent's stylesheet (or by user styles, if any exist).

not quite true. For many inherited properties, the declaration `property: revert;` actually has the same effect as `property: inherit;`, i.e. the calculated value of the parent element is adopted. Exceptions are the form elements `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`, where the user agent breaks the chain of inheritance and sets explicit values for `font-family` and the `font-size`. The value `revert` then causes the values of the user agent to be adopted for these elements. For non-inherited properties, the value that results solely from the cascade of user and user agent is always taken. I give the following example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Testing Global Values and Shorthand Property all</title>
  <style>
    body, div{border: solid 2px;padding:10px;margin: 10px;}
    .all-revert { all:revert;}
    div{ font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace; }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="font-family:serif;color:royalblue;font-size: 24px;">
  <div class="all-revert">Default serif (TNR), no margin, no border.</div>
  <div>Courier New, margin of 20 pixels, and border.</div>
  <button class="all-revert">Arial</button>
  <button style="all:unset; border:revert;">Default serif</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The `div, button {all: revert;}` rule affects the `div` element differently than the `button` element. In the case of the `div` element, all properties related to the font are given the value `inherit`, which means that the settings made in the body element are applied to these properties. For the `button` element, on the other hand, the default values selected by the user agent for the color, size, and type of the font are inherited.

The value `unset` has the same effect on inherited properties as `inherit`, so the font properties of the second button are inherited from the body element, while the border inherits the settings made by the user agent. As for non-inherited properties like `border`, `padding`, and `margin`, the 'revert' value causes the user agent's values to be adopted.