# How can I restore button default styles?

Tags: html, css, button

I'd like to reset a `<button>` to browser defaults in the high contrast mode of our website. Simply removing the styles is not an option as I would have to change a lot of code.

I thought this would be an easy task by assigning `initial` to every changed CSS property. Turns out, it doesn't work: while some properties are actually reset, the browser won't apply its original background-color and border and, in the case of Chrome, the text color when the button is disabled.

Is there a way to do this or can I only approximately reconstruct the browser defaults? And what is `initial` for if not for that?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wortwart/vk4nxw0u/13/) showcasing the problem.

Comment: Can you share your button css code? Depending on the css property, initial is not enough.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste: Updated with JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 3):

> While some properties are actually resetted, the browser won't apply
>   its original background-color and border

It looks to me like the OP is looking for the `revert` value functionality.

See [the spec regarding `revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default) - one of the CSS-wide property values:

> Rolls back the cascaded value to the user level, so that the specified
>   value is calculated as if no author-level rules were specified for
>   this property on this element. ...

Unfortunately, the `revert` value is currently [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value).

Caniuse on revert actually nicely summarizes (and also hi lights the difference between revert and initial)

> A CSS keyword value that resets a property's value to the default
>   specified by the browser in its UA stylesheet, as if the webpage had
>   not included any CSS. For example, `display:revert` on a `<div>` would
>   result in `display:block`. This is in contrast to the initial value,
>   which is simply defined on a per-property basis, and for `display` would
>   be `inline`.

Comment: Yes, that could be the solution - if the browser support was acceptable.

Comment: Update: `revert` is now supported by all relevant browsers!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your html for high contrast mode has a parent with a class... let's say as an example you have the class "highcm" at body

You could change your actual css sheet where you have styled your buttons to something like:

```
body:not(.highcm) .youractualclass  button {
    color: red;
}
```

This way just your button with not "highcm" at body will be styled while the rest will be rendered  browser defaults

Comment: This is the most realistic way to do this.`all: intial` should do it according to the spec, _"resets all of the selected element's properties to their initial values as defined in the CSS spec"_, but it seems this isn't correctly respected for buttons by some browsers. Even adding to the unset, `-webkit-appearance: button`, doesn't correct for this.

Comment: I suppose the solution will look something like that. Anyway I still find it hard to believe that it's not possible to tell the browser "ignore my previous CSS, just use your default styling".