# What are the advantages of using a reset style sheet instead of all:unset?

Tags: css

Why should I use a Reset Style Sheet like "Normalize", when I can simply write the following CSS

```css
*
{
    all: unset;
}
```

Comment: (1) unset is a new value not supported everywhere and normalize is very very old (2) it will not necessarely give you what you want (related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333)

Comment: ^ the trivial example will be display set to inline for `p` elements (and div, section, ul, .. all the elements)

Comment: also missing here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all some official reference to start from ;)

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406128/to-reopen-a-question-by-another-guy-i-dont-think-it-is-really-opinion-based/406132#406132). Suggestion: hold close and reopen votes until a consensus is reached.

Comment: Never reset styles for `*`. Only reset styles for those elements that you know exist, and you know exactly how they should appear. Otherwise, if a tag that has not been specifically styled in the style sheet ends up within your document (perhaps from a future version of the HTML spec?), it will not even have the browser’s default fallback style, and it may end up being unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `all: unset` revert all the styling to its initial value or inherent value. and the initial values sometimes are not like the user-agent one that every browser defines differently (one example is that the initial value for display is `inline` and not `block`). using "Normalize" builds and reverts the styles on top of the user-agent defaults.

in the future you could use `all: revert` that revert to the user-agent styling.

Comment: using `all:revert` is useless because like you said it will revert to user-agent and if we have no CSS then by default the user-agent will apply so it cannot replace normalize

Comment: here is a pen showing the difference while switching in between `initial` , `revert` and `unset` ... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/NWPemmO  use `*{all:/* initial | inherit | unset | revert*/} ` with lots of caution ;)

Comment: Initial or INHERITED value ! Not "inherent"…

Answer (score -1):

First, I would make a remark that using `unset` is superfluous; `initial` is enough:

```
* { all: initial; }
```

The problem with that approach is that it resets literally everything. This is just too much.

```html
<style>
  * {
    all: initial;
  }
</style>

<h1>Heading<sup>1</sup></h1>

<p>I am a paragraph.</p>
<p>I am another paragraph.</p>

<script>
  // do something
</script>
```

Output:

> [image]

See? Do you want paragraphs to go inline? Do you want `<style>` and `<script>` tags to be shown? Usually, you don't.

#### `<sidenote>`

We can workaround the second issue by using `:not`, though:

```html
*:not(style, script) {
  all: initial;
}
```

#### `</sidenote>`

Each browser has its own built-in style sheet, a so-called *user agent style sheet*. These built-in style sheets have some inconsistencies, but in most aspects, they are identical.

Things like `reset.css` or `normalize.css` simply remove these inconsistencies. That is, they are not as aggressive as `* { all: initial; }`.

---

Which approach is better? To be honest, they are both terrible. Things like `normalize.css` is a kind of bloatware and `* { all: initial; }` requires you to manually undo a lot of resets that you normally won't want.

Comment: Granted, using all: initial/unset is a great way to challenge yourself to try to reproduce a typical UA stylesheet.