# Why is the 'initial' property not working for me?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create something like a native styling rule for the interactive html elements I use, therefor I'm using a **type**-selector, which if exchanged with the **class**-selector makes no visible difference at all - as far as I and the dev-tools can tell. I'm using the **initial** property to reset my custom to the browser's native styling. BUT whatever I try - it won't work out. My concern is that I'm doing something just **slightly** wrong, but I just can't tell. Please help me out! Thanks in advance!

I've posted an example of all my code I use so far below to make following along easier.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

ul a, ol a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

a {
  color: #2196f3;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a[type="nativeStyling"] {
  color: initial;
  background-color: initial;
  text-decoration: initial;
}
a[type="nativeStyling"]:hover {
  text-decoration: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" type="nativeStyling">I'm an anchor tag</a>
```

Comment: `nativeStyling` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute. Only MIME types (such as `text/html`) are allowed.

Comment: *I'm using the initial property to reset my custom to the brower's native styling.* --> you are looking for `revert` not `initial` related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, but as told, using a class selectors makes no difference at all.

Comment: @Simpliciss — I didn't say you should use a class selector. I said your HTML was flat out wrong.

Comment: @TemaniAfif maybe it's just me, but it doesnt work out, now the styling is just being inherited from the class-rule above.

Comment: use a custom data attribute `data-my-type` instead of `type` . As @Quentin said, the way you are using the type attribute is not correct and results in an invalid HTML structure.

Comment: @Simpliciss — No it isn't, it is getting the initial value for the color property.

Comment: @MihaiT, thanks, but even using the class-selector results in no difference

Comment: @Simpliciss because it's not yet supported (try on firefox)

Comment: @Simpliciss have you read this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial ? check the ' NOTE '. Might help

Comment: @quentin, but hasn't the anchor tag a specific initial color property as displayed in chrome, firefox etc? I'm trying to get this.

Comment: @MihaiT, I appreciate your help, but I already checked all that

Comment: @TemaniAfif, hm, running it in firefox makes no difference for me, I still belive Ive somehow managed to pass an error in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The `initial` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) is applying to your a element just fine, the problem is that it doesn't do what you think it does. It resets the value to the initial value for that *property* (which, in this case, is `black`).

This is **not** the same as the default value for that *property **plus** the effects of the browser's default stylesheet*.

You might want [the `revert` value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert), but that is currently only [supported by Firefox and Safari](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value).

```css
a { display: block; color: pink }

.i { color: initial; }

.r { color: revert; }
```

```html
<a class="i" href="http://example.com/">One</a>
<a class="r" href="http://example.com/">Two</a>
<a class="x" href="http://example.com/">Three</a>
```