# css invalid property value on all revert

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to revert the style applied to a child element to default values but I'm getting `Invalid Property Value`

**HTML**:

```
<div class="dropdown locale-selector">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary " type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
   Dropdown button
   </button>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="">
      English
      </a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="">
      español
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.locale-selector a {
    all: revert;
}
```

**CSS error:**

```
Invalid Property Value all: revert
```

Comment: Which browser are you using seems like revert is not supported in the browser you are using

Comment: more browser dosent support this 
https://caniuse.com/#search=all%3A%20revert

Comment: yes you are right the original idea goes back to 2015 so I assumed it would be widely supported by now. but that is not the case! thanks

Comment: @Ademyalçın if you put the link as Answer ill be happy to accept it as right answer

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691991/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Q4 2020, the `revert` CSS property is now natively supported in current versions of *all 4* of the major desktop browsers, including Firefox<sup>v67+</sup>, Safari<sup>v9.1+</sup>, Chrome<sup>v84+</sup>, and Edge<sup>v84+</sup>.

Mobile support is spottier, though current versions of iOS Safari<sup>iOS 9.3+</sup>, Android Firefox<sup>v79</sup> and Android Chrome<sup>v85</sup> all support it.

Current stats can be viewed at the [`revert` CanIUse.com page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, **"all:revert"** will never work for Internet Explorer. Maybe that is what you are seeing. Also, what "all:revert" does is the following:

1. Clears out every CSS property value you assigned directly to your element.
2. Any inheriting properties (usually text-based like font, etc) in your element from any parents above the element are now assigned to the element through normal inheritance.
3. Any non-inheritable properties (like display or border, etc.) are removed from the element and assigned values found in the browser UA style sheet or user style sheet. All other styles for those properties on that element are ignored. This is usually the default style sheet the browser came with and what many call a "reset".
4. This assumes you do not have more selective styles that cascade over "revert" for any property on the element you are reverting. "all:revert" is just like any other CSS property so anything that cascades over any property on that element would win.

So if you assigned a special "font" (inheritable) to that div, it would be removed and and it would now inherit the font setting in the cascade from the parent tree above your div. It could be several parents up. But if you assigned a custom "border" value (non-inheritable), that would be removed and the browser's default value for "border" on "div" assigned in your browser's UA style sheet would be used. This is almost always "none" for "border on "div".

BTW....."all:unset" works the same but falls back to "initial" for non-inheritable properties which isn't the browsers default or even the element's for that property but the universal default value for the property itself regardless of the element using it. That is quite nasty and not what most people want.

WHAT THIS MEANS FOR YOU is non-inheritable changes by "all:revert" wouldn't affect your children's styles as they aren't inherited anyway (like display or border) unless you set those to inherit explicitly from your children. But inheritable settings like fonts, color, line-height etc would suddenly see themselves using styles from farther up your parent tree coming down. Because in CSS distance of parent doesn't affect selectivity, it shouldn't have more weight but might be the changes you are seeing.

So if you see text-based "weirdness" I would look at what new styles are inherited from parents above this code you posted. I would NOT use "all:revert" above a block of markup as it just adds confusion. If you use revert, use it only on specific elements to reset them individually back to browser defaults on non-inheritable values or on every element to reset the whole page, inheritable and non-inheritable, back to browser defaults.