# Why "all: initial" makes <style> tag visible? And how do I reset everything to initial state in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a plugin that dynamically generates a container on any page.

Because there might be some predefined rules that change the appearance of the contents inside my `.my-plugin`, so I set

```css
.my-plugin * {
  all: inital;
}
```

to the `<style>` tag inside of it.

But somehow it makes the `<style>` tag visible:

```css
/* The style that from the page, which is uncertain */
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is red</h1>

<!-- dynamically injected code -->
<div class="my-plugin">
  <style>
    .my-plugin * {
      /* reset everything to default state */
      all: initial;
    }
    
    .my-plugin {
      border: solid 1px black;
    }
  </style>
  
  <h1>This is not red</h1>
</div>
```

How do I set everything inside a tag back to their initial states?

I know I can do something like `.my-plugin style { display: none; }`, but what about other tags that should not be invisible as well?

Ultimately I just don't want the `h1` inside `.my-plugin` to be red.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`initial` for display is `inline` for all elements which obviously includes  `style` elements. This overrides the `display:none` style applied by the user-agent style sheet.

To get the styles as they were before the author styles start being applied, what you really want is `{ all: revert; }` but [the browser compatibility is not good](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert#Browser_compatibility) yet.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that, but like you said the compatibility is awful... Guess at this point I have to go for some workaround