# What is the documented effect of `display: initial` on table rows?

Tags: html, css, display

Why does `tr { display:initial }` cause the `td colspan=5` to be ignored?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        * { border-style: solid; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td colspan="5">cs=5</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
        <tr style="display: initial"> <td colspan="5">cs=5,d=i</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

"inherit" has the same wrong effect.

The real situation is attempting to use JavaScript to toggle the display between "none" and "initial".

Comment: A good practice is to toggle a class instead style ... to avoid this kind of issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is to toggle between `none` and `table-row`.

But good question! I can't explain why `initial` doesn't work as expected.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        * { border-style: solid; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td colspan="5">cs=5</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
        <tr style="display: table-row"> <td colspan="5">cs=5,d=i</td> </tr>
        <tr> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> <td>×</td> </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "table-row" works great, thanks.  But I'm still curious about why "initial" doesn't work. If "initial" doesn't set it to "table-row", what *does* it set it to?

Comment: The result of `initial` looks like `inline` is applied.

Comment: Yes, chrome's "inspect" confirms that it does get reset to "inline".  It sounds like a bug, but Firefox, Chrome, and MS Edge all do the same thing.

Comment: @RayButterworth initial doesn't depend on the element, it only depends on the property and each property has ONE initial value defined in the Spec and it's inline for display

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks, that makes sense.  It's not reasonable, but at least I now understand.

Comment: @RayButterworth *It's not reasonable* --> it's ;) what you are looking for is `revert`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Comment: If you inspect, you will notice that `table-row` comes from the *user agent stylesheet*.