# why does setting h1 all: intial makes it 19px

Tags: html, css, firefox, frontend

I want to make a part of my website display html in its defualt style essentially ignoring all other css files only for certain elements.

So I try all: initial !important; It gives me the output I want but when using h1 tag the output  text has font-size 19px which should be 32px instead, is there something I am doing wrong or is this a browser bug?

edit: when using revert I get weard effect see:https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8UED.jpg
for more explanation see my comment below this post

Comment: you are looking for `revert` not initial: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333

Comment: I did try it before an didn't work but when giving it another try I found out that it works for some selection types but not all like when I use * to select all elments and set the color for example to red and I revert only one to by class selector   all: revert !important; it doesn't work while showing in  in firefox inspector  as crossed, but when using h1 as a selector for red color and defualt using class selector  and all: revert !important; I get wanted result,why is that? here is an image for examples :  [link](https://imgur.com/a/pEmJFpw)

Comment: because of inheritance, the `*` will also select the body tag and h1 will inherit that value since there is no default browser color to revert to

Comment: Thank you How should I end the question?I am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the use of `revert`

> The revert CSS keyword reverts the cascaded value of the property from its current value to the value the property would have had if no changes had been made by the current style origin to the current element. Thus, it resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent **or to the default value established by the user agent's stylesheet** <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)</sup>

`initial` won't be good because it does something different

> The initial CSS keyword applies **the initial (or default) value of a property** to an element. It can be applied to any CSS property. This includes the CSS shorthand all, with which initial can be used to restore all CSS properties to their initial state.

Note the *of a property*. So initial won't consider the default CSS of the browser.

Related: [What's the difference between `all: unset` and `all: revert'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58691846/8620333)