# Why does a CSS property inherit parameters even though there is a class defined?

Tags: html, css

```css
p {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}

.x {
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<p class="x">Arosh </p> <p>Jayamanna</p>
```

Above is my code. I expected the blue box to have no height or width as I did not define it within the specific class I created (class x). But it inherited the height and the width. Why is that?

Comment: It is applying the `p` properties. If you don't want any hight then you need specifically mentioned in your `.x` class. otherwise change the `<p class="x">Arosh</p>` to `<div classs="x">Arosh</div>`

Comment: there is no inheritance here. the selector `p` will target both elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is how the `CSS` inherit will work. If you don't want to inherit all your parent style then there is a property called `all:revert` and it will work for all the modern browsers. You have to add this as the first property in your declaration, so that it will remove all the inherited properties then you can apply your own styles.

```
 .x {
   all: revert; /* remove all the inherited properties */
   background-color:blue;
 }
```

```css
p {
  background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}

.x {
  all: revert;
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<p class="x">Arosh </p> <p>Jayamanna</p>
```

There is another property called `unset` and that is also do the same stuff except some browser style. You can find more information about what is the difference between these two properties in the below link.

[What's the difference between all: unset and all: revert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58691846/whats-the-difference-between-all-unset-and-all-revert)

Comment: there is no inheritance here

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance in your case. The selector `p` will target both elements. Simply be more specific with your selectors and target only the needed elements:

```css
p:not([class]) { /* I will target only the p element without classes */
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.x {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="x">Arosh </p>
<p>Jayamanna</p>
```